# Custom checkbox changing position on click

Tags: css, angularjs, checkbox

I think I am missing something but I can't find a solution to the following problem.

I am using custom checkboxes on a list of sentences. At first it looks good but once you check the first checkbox, it moves.
I can't find out why the checkboxes move once you check them?

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Hodor_/vhhj7huv/
I have noticed that by changing `content: "/2714";` to `content: "";`
the checkbox doesn't move on click.

Can't understand how the content affects the position of the checkbox.

In other questions I saw recommendations to use vertical-align:middle, it doesn't work for me.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which browser you are using because for me on Chrome your code is working just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with your usage of `display: flex` in conjuncture with `position: absolute`. It doesn't always work well.

To fix this you need to make **3 simple changes**:

1) Remove `position: absolute` from your `label:before`

2) Remove `padding: 0 0 0 50px;` from your `label`

3) Add a `margin-right: 20px`(or any you want) to the `label:before`.

Simple.. So your final code looks like - [Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/vhhj7huv/3/)

```
label{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 30px;
  cursor:pointer;
  color black;
}

label:before{
  /* position:absolute; */
  content:"";
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  left: 25px;
  text-align:center;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid #9b9b9b;
  border-radius: 4px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

> Remember: `flexbox` allows you to have a "**flexible**" or flow like control over your elements, it gives a more flexible nature to your elements positioning elements on its own based on your requirements.
>
> `position: absolute` on the other hand does the exact **opposite**. It takes the element out of the document and lets you place it where you want via directions(`left`, `right`, `top`, `bottom`), its more like a "**rigid**" or stubborn way of controlling your elements.

Comment: Thanks you for the elaboration. Couldn't understand how to position the :before element so tried it in several ways. Now that you mentioned it, using position absolute was not such a good practice.. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I used `text-indent` to hide the content, so basically the content is always there and the checkbox now is not moving.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/vhhj7huv/2/) the working fiddle.

Comment: Tried it and it also worked. Liked @NikhilNanjappa 's solution better because of a better practice in my opinion.. Up voted your answer anyway. Thanks.